# KeyboardType namePhonePad in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard

In iOS, we have keyboard type **namePhonePad** and the Normal behavior of this keyboard type is as shown in the below snapshot.

[image]

> and the output is, (This is what I want in Flutter)

[image]

This is the output of iOS's **namePhonePad** keyboard type.

I want the same behavior for the flutter keyboard type.

I have reviewed and there is no **namePhonePad** keyboard type in a flutter. We have separate types like phone, number, name, etc,
but not **namePhonePad**

Flutter's output is,
[image]

Comment: Add some code, What you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the package [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions)

Comment: Yes, we can create a custom keyboard with the help of keyboard_actions. But I was looking for a stable solution. Although for now, It's good to go with this package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyboardType` of `TextFormField` widget with `TextInputType.number` and `FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`... example:

```
Expanded(
     child: TextFormField(
     controller: txt_identidad,
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
       FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
     ],
   ),
 ),
```